# How to install libsvm in matlab

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I'm using windows 7 and Matlab_R2011a. I'm trying to install LibSVM in these environments. I already installed Command Line Tools and I am trying to "make" file (go to unpacked folder of LibSVM on my Desktop, go to folder matlab and run "make"). However, I receive a compilers options as 0 and 1 but I couldn't find visual studio compiler even though I installed VS 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler version may not be supported/compatible with MATLAB R2011a.
First check Matlab page 'Supported and Compatible Compilers – Release R2011a' and then specify the version number.

For ex,if g++ X.Y is supported, replace CXX = g++ in the Makefile with CXX = g++-X.Y

Comment: Nothing like  CXX = g++ is there in the make file